# Android M + RetroFit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, android-6.0-marshmallow

Well i've tried looking everywhere before posting this question.
I am working on an application that implements Retrofit to handle all server interactions. everthing is working okay but when i tested the app on android M (Device : huawei P9/ P9 Lite)
the callbacks of retrofit are getting called only when the device is connected WIFI.
To be specific :

```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(Constants.SECONDARY_BASE_URL)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                .build();
                        RestaurantApi restaurantApi = retrofit.create(RestaurantApi.class);
                        Call<ServerResponse> call = restaurantApi.deleteFromFavoris(preferences.getInt("id", 0), getArguments().getInt("idResto"));
                        //asynchronous bestOfCall
                        call.enqueue(BestOfFragment.this);
```

as you can see it's a straight forward call nothing fancy. yet for some reason the call back is never called (with no messages or exceptions on the android monitor) when the phone is using mobile data. and he're the callback

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
    if (response.code() == 200) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Supprimé des favoris", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getArguments().putBoolean("isFavoris", false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Désolé une erreur inattendue est survenue !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exception that is raised? Or the error code...

Comment: Did you set the network permissions in the manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Also, does your device have data disabled for cellular?

Comment: Every other call within the application works fine.
The permission is declared in the manifest.
The wierd thing only in this case the callback is never called ( i even tried lowering the timeout time ) nothing. i'm using a fragment pager adapter with fragments in it within the fragment i intercept a click event to start this call
the call is executed but the callback is never triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify first if the device has a mobile internet connection:

```
public  void hasNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No internet !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (networkInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        if (networkInfo.isConnected())
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Mobile internet !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (networkInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
        if (networkInfo.isConnected())
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Wifi internet !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And you can add an else for non 200 code response:

```
@Override
 public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
if (response.code() == 200) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Supprimé des favoris", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getArguments().putBoolean("isFavoris", false);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "no 200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Already checked the Cellular data is up and running (LTE Network)

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe you doesn't have a 200 code response from mobile network.

Comment: i'll try and tell you